# Java: test System output including "new lines" with assertEquals

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm currently writing a Unit Test for the Strategy Design Pattern. I'm comparing the System output with a string in the assertEquals method.The output looks the same but my test keeps failing.. . I'm thinking that I'm forgetting something to do with new lines or tabs?

My Unit Test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MiniDuck1Test {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(null);
        System.setErr(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDuck1() {       
        Duck mallard = new MallardDuck();
        mallard.performQuack();
        mallard.performFly();

        Duck model = new ModelDuck();
        model.performFly();
        model.setFlyBehavior(new FlyRocketPowered());
        model.performFly();

        assertEquals("Quack\nI'm flying!!\nI can't fly\nI'm flying with a rocket", outContent.toString().trim());
    }
}
```

Output (second and third line appear red):

```
Quack
I'm flying!!
I can't fly
I'm flying with a rocket
```

**Edit:**

The quickest solution seemed to be adding an "\r" in front of my "\n". Multiple answers informed me that this needs to be done for Windows. After applying this my assertEquals looked like:

```
assertEquals("Quack\r\nI'm flying!!\r\nI can't fly\r\nI'm flying with a rocket", outContent.toString().trim());
```

Also: I forgot to mention that most of the code came from the book: "Head First Design Patterns" by Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Robson, Bert Bates and Kathy Sierra.

Comment: Instead of `Assert.equals()`, `TestCase.equals()` does a good job at displaying the error position of a mismatching String. Just edit your import statements accordingly.

Comment: Try comparing the length of your strings. It might be `\r\n` as some have suggested, or some other invisible discrepancy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to the other answers if you are looking for a platform-independent way...

A quick platform-independent solution can be to replace the line separators

```
String expected = "Quack\nI'm flying!!\nI can't fly\nI'm flying with a rocket"
                       .replaceAll("\\n|\\r\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString().trim());
```

or using a `PrintWriter` to build the expected string.

```
StringWriter expectedStringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(expectedStringWriter);

printWriter.println("Quack");
printWriter.println("I'm flying!!");
printWriter.println("I can't fly");
printWriter.println("I'm flying with a rocket");
printWriter.close();

String expected = expectedStringWriter.toString();
assertEquals(expected, outContent.toString());
```

or create an own assert class to re-use it

```
class MyAssert {

    public static void assertLinesEqual(String expectedString, String actualString){
        BufferedReader expectedLinesReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(expectedString));
        BufferedReader actualLinesReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(actualString));

        try {
            int lineNumber = 0;

            String actualLine;
            while((actualLine = actualLinesReader.readLine()) != null){
                String expectedLine = expectedLinesReader.readLine();
                Assert.assertEquals("Line " + lineNumber, expectedLine, actualLine);
                lineNumber++;
            }

            if(expectedLinesReader.readLine() != null){
                Assert.fail("Actual string does not contain all expected lines");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                expectedLinesReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                actualLinesReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can give a better problem description if the test fails. E.g.

```
MyAssert.assertLinesEqual(
         "Quack\nI'm flying!!\nI can not fly\nI'm flying with a rocket\n",
         outContent.toString());
```

will output

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Line 2 
Expected :I can not fly
Actual   :I can't fly
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using \r\n instead of \n.

```
assertEquals("Quack\r\nI'm flying!!\r\nI can't fly\r\nI'm flying with a rocket", outContent.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

So far **all** the other answers are technically correct; but still they are don't mention one core thing: it is simply bad practice to *capture* stdout/stderr and then do exact string matching; **assuming** that your class writes there.

Even more when you are testing **multiple** method calls, and expect that some *final* output "proves" that all the methods were called, and so on.

So, yes, theoretically you can do things this way (for training/learning purposes); but the "pattern" that you are using here is simply spoken "bad practice". What happens when you later decide to remove those print statements (because, well, production code **doesn't do** print statements). Then all your tests render worthless. Or when some other user changes one character in the strings going to stdout?

Thus: the real answer is to step back and consider what the real "side effects" could be that these method calls will cause; and look for better ways to verify them.

Comment: what if you want to test the output because you are developping an app that runs on the command line ?

Comment: Simple: then you have a component that **creates** messages. That you test. Then you have a component responsible for taking messages and writing them somewhere, for example to stdout. That you test. And again - no need to test the *layout* of your messages by reading from stdout! Think "segregation of concerns" and "single responsibility principle"!

Comment: this is fine for unit testing but how do you do an integration test that proves the following situation:  
- print to an output buffer some text, says 10 lines
- print some escape codes like "move line up" + "clear line" 4 times
- print 3 other lines
how do you assert that the final output contains the text of the 9 final lines (10 + - 4 + 3) ?

Comment: Interesting point. I guess I would try to get a "mock" representing the thing that is written to. Something that records exactly what comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be, that you are on a Windows system and need to check for `\r\n` instead of just `\n`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse in Windows 10. Solved it