# Result of Outputstream needs to be comparable to a list

Tags: java, junit, outputstream

I need to code a method which allows me to input a list of strings give them to a OutputStream object and give it back and it needs to be comparable via a JUnit test.

My method:

```
     public void gebeAus(OutputStream out, StringListe zeilen) {
    
    byte[] bytesArr;
    
    try {
    for(int i = 0; i < zeilen.size(); i++) {
        bytesArr = zeilen.get(i).getBytes();
        
        out.write(bytesArr);
        out.write('\n');
    }   
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

The part of the JUnit test which I wrote into a test class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortTest {
    
    private static String[] strings = { "Das", "ist", "ein", "Test", "zum", "Sortieren", "von", "Strings" };
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateiSortierer ds = new DateiSortierer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String[] test = {"asfas", "aws", "jzrfjc", "dfhfds", "asfewfg", "wertgwertw"};
    StringListe l = new StringListe();
    l.addAll(Arrays.asList(test));
    ds.gebeAus(baos, l);
    System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println(baos);
}

}
```

The output of list is [asfas, aws, jzrfjc, dfhfds, asfewfg, wertgwertw] while the output of my OutputStream is
asfas
aws
jzrfjc
dfhfds
asfewfg
wertgwertw

The Junit test results in failure here.

DateiSortierer:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 
public class DateiSortierer {

    
    
    
    public StringListe einlesen(String dateiname) throws DateiNichtGefundenAusnahme, IOException   {
        
        StringListe liste1 = new StringListe();
        
        File file = new File(dateiname);
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new DateiNichtGefundenAusnahme(dateiname);
        }
        
        try {
                String line = br.readLine();
                
                while (line != null) {
                    liste1.add(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
            finally {
                br.close();
            }
            return liste1;
    }
    
    public StringListe sortiere(StringListe unsortierteListe) 
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        
        if(unsortierteListe == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null ist ein ungueltiges Argument.");
        }
        
        try {
            Collections.sort(unsortierteListe);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            
        }
        return unsortierteListe;
    }
    
     public void gebeAus(OutputStream out, StringListe zeilen) {
        
        byte[] bytesArr;
        
        try {
        for(int i = 0; i < zeilen.size(); i++) {
            bytesArr = zeilen.get(i).getBytes();
            
            out.write(bytesArr);
            out.write('\n');
        }   
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
     }
         
    
    public void sortiereDatei(String dateiname) {
        DateiSortierer listen = new DateiSortierer();
        listen.einlesen(dateiname);
        listen.sortiere(listen);
        listen.gebeAus(out, zeilen);
    }
    
}
```

StringListe:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * eine Liste die Zeichenketten enthaelt
 * @author schreier
 *
 */
public class StringListe extends LinkedList<String> {

    /**
     * erzeugt eine neue leere Liste
     */
    public StringListe() {
        List<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think I have to manage to get both to a String[]...

Comment: You are not using JUnit to do that test. I think if that is what you want you should refactor your code and create a test class with a method annotated with `@Test`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676677/11754886). Particularly the  `assertLinesEqual()` method to compare lists/arrays. I think that may work for you as long as you have two arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I just took the piece of code from the Junit test. It was easier for me. My question is how to get the same output results here? So that I get [asfas, aws, jzrfjc, dfhfds, asfewfg, wertgwertw] while using OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

For what I could gather, adding the following line to your code should fix your problem:

```
String decodedBaos = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You can compare `decodedBaos` with `l`. As I commented, I suggest you use the method `assertLinesEqual()` for that.

Answer (score -1):

While use out.write it missed out.write('\r'). Including it the test is fine.

Comment: You should not answer your own question to include more information about the question. You should remove this answer and edit your question or maybe comment it.

Comment: Nonsense. You were writing binary data followed by a linefeed. Java understands CR, LF, and CRLF as line terminators already, so adding a CR changed nothing. The problem was the binary data, which can *also* contain any of those characters.